# jestjs test multipul api responses one at a time and not wait till all are finished

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am trying to test my logic with Jest of downloading multiple files. 
I have a list of files Ids for each file I go fetch the blob with an ajax call, an anchor(link) is added once a response from an API is received then a click is triggered and removed mideatly. that will trigger the download. The download logic is working as expected as one file is fetched and downloaded the other file is fetched and downloaded.

If I run this logic with one download file it could find the element 'downloadFileLink'. if I run with more the one file it can't find the element.

it seems like the first await is waiting till all calls are finished. (If I print the value of seconedCountCalls in the first await it is 1 should be 0) How do I test each call before the other one is run?

```
// after each fetch this is the download logic that is called
const downloadFile = (downloadMeta, downloadLink) => {
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = downloadLink;
  a.target = "_parent";
  a.download = downloadMeta.fileMeta?._id;
  a.setAttribute("data-testid", "downloadFileLink");
  a.style.display = "none";
  (document.body || document.documentElement).appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  setTimeout(() => {
    a!.parentNode!.removeChild(a);
  }, 0);
};
```

```
   let firstCountCalls = 0,
      secondImgCheckbox = 0;

   // mocking the API call of the first file
   mock.get(
      /files\/media\/exams\/3b650f70-d8a6-4135-8570-6d2510869930\/files\/45ddf63a-32e0-4a89-8bd5-ffe843cc63f3/i,
      once((req, res) => {
        firstCountCalls += 1;
        spyReq = req;
        return res.status(200).body(new Blob([""], { type: "image/jpeg" }));
      })
    );

    // mocking the API call of the second file
    mock.get(
      /files\/media\/exams\/3b650f70-d8a6-4135-8570-6d2510869930\/files\/45d8f63a-32e0-4a89-8bd5-ffe843cc63f4/i,
      once((req, res) => {
        seconedCountCalls += 1;
        spyReq = req;
        return res.status(200).body(new Blob([""], { type: "image/jpeg" }));
      })
    );

    // trigger start download 
    const downloadButton = comp.getByTestId("download-imgs-button");
    expect(downloadButton).not.toBeDisabled();
    fireEvent.click(downloadButton);
    expect(downloadButton).toBeDisabled();
    // waiting for first fetch of blob from API
    await wait(() => {
      expect(firstCountCalls).toBe(1);
      const downloadImageLink = comp.getByTestId( <-------- falls here can't find the item
        "downloadFileLink"
      ) as HTMLAnchorElement;
      expect(downloadImageLink.download).toEqual(
        "45ddf63a-32e0-4a89-8bd5-ffe843cc63f3"
      );
    });

    // waiting for second fetch of blob from API
    await wait(() => {
      expect(secondImgCheckbox).toBe(1);
      const downloadImageLink = comp.getByTestId(
        "downloadFileLink"
      ) as HTMLAnchorElement;
      expect(downloadImageLink.download).toEqual(
        "45ddf63a-32e0-4a89-8bd5-ffe843cc63f3"
      );
    });
```

Thanks in advance.